# How to make read -d return true

Tags: bash

I am using the following construct to set a multiline string in bash shell. But this always returns false which does not work when I set `set -e`. How can I make this to return success?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e

read -d '' QUERY <<EOF
UPDATE table_name SET
 field1 = 'value',
 field2 = 'value'
 WHERE id = 1;
EOF
mysql table_name -e "$QUERY"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not an answer to your original question, this does get your problem solved. Consider using substitution and e.g. `cat`

```
QUERY=$(cat <<EOM
test
test2
EOM
)

mysql table_name -e "$QUERY"
```

Please, be aware of safety issues if you're reading those values from unsanitized input.

Comment: @codefx, you've unaccepted this answer. Would you care to add a comment explaining why this solution once worked and now no longer answers the question you've asked? It would be educational, not just for me, but also for others looking for a similar solution.